# How to explain why there is no curve to the left of the $y$-axis?

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

The question required the plot of the polar graph for $\;r=4\cos\theta\sin^2\theta\;$.

[image: This is the graph that plotted using Maple]

How to explain why there is no curve on the left side of the $y$-axis? Should I show all the calculations to explain it?

Comment: Could you, perhaps name the software you are using? It looks fairly neat.

Comment: Thank you. I use Maple Software to plot the graph.

Answer (score 4):

It is because $\cos\theta$ becomes negative on the left of the $y$-axis, which results in negative $r$. That means that $r$ maps from 2nd quadrant to the 4th, and from the 3rd one to the 1st. You may convince yourself by direct substitution that $r(\theta)$ and $r(\theta+\pi)$ map to the same point.

Comment: Symmetry test can be used to answer this question?

Comment: What do you mean by "symmetry test"? If my answer needs some additional explanations please let me know.